# extern alias with same assembly file name

Tags: c#, alias, extern, assembly-references

I have a problem that could be viewed as an extension of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502640/the-extern-alias-xxx-was-not-specified-in-a-reference-option) question in which the user is having problems with external aliases not working.

The variation I am experiencing is that the two projects output the same file name.  The first (we'll call *Legacy* since it's the older version) contains classes which have been binary-serialized.  The second (*Current*) is the next version of my domain.  I'm trying to create a conversion library (*Compatibility*) which will map *Legacy* to *Current* for use in the new domain.

Because both projects build to MyApp.Domain.dll, one is overwritten by the other when the assemblies are copied into the output folder for *Compatibility*.  When this happens, the compiler can't recognize that I have two versions of the same assembly because I actually have only one file with that name.

It looks something like this:

```
Project          Output

MyApp            MyApp.exe
Legacy           MyApp.Domain.dll
Current          MyApp.Domain.dll
```

I realize that one solution would be to alter the output file name of *Current* (adding a 'V2' or similar), but I'd prefer not to if it can be avoided; I like keeping the 'MyApp.Domain' signature.  Alternatively, is there a way I can instruct the compiler to copy the output of *Legacy* into a subfolder of the output folder and then reference them there?  Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need a way to reference 2 different versions of the same 3rd party DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550981/need-a-way-to-reference-2-different-versions-of-the-same-3rd-party-dll)