# BouncyCastle in conflict with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext, bouncycastle

I have a c# program that uses BouncyCastle. If I insert a reference to iTextSharp, the compiler generates many errors of classes already existing in both references. I have specified all the namespaces but it does not change anything. 
Example:

```
 Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate certCopy = DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(oCertificato);
```

How can I use BouncyCastle and iTextSharp together?

Comment: You should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672920/two-different-dll-with-same-namespace) SO question and have a look at [this GitHub source](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/9d04600a8c79fdfdf0cfc4ad395e6818b21de0a4/src/core/srcbc/security/DotNetUtilities.cs)

Comment: I solved by changing only the alias in the properties of the iTextSharp dll. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Did you know that you can answer your own question if you found a solution for yourself? This will help others as well...

Comment: For anyone else: if you change the alias in the reference properties for iTextSharp from "global" to, say "iText", then you using statement will be

`extern alias iText;`
`using iText::iTextSharp.text.pdf;`

Comment: if you're having issues adding the `alias`, you might need to manually edit the csproj. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55986973/426315 for more details

Answer (score 7):

Just like @franco-de-giorgi said. Add an Alias to the library.

I'm just writing a full answer because I had to learn what is an Alias and how to add and Alias

Go to your references and go to properties on BouncyCastle, then change global to your personal Alias:

[image]

Then in your class use an external alias to your references like this (instead of using)

```
//using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
extern alias Merged;
```

In your classes add your alias

```
new Merged::Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader
```

Comment: add extern above all using statement.

Comment: I only add the alias and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: Use the PackageReference's `Aliases` attribute in `*.csproj` and add the alias to the affected `*.cs` files:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="PackageAffectedByConflict" Aliases="AltGlobalNamespace" />
```

```cs
extern alias AltGlobalNamespace;

using AltGlobalNamespace.ConflictedName;
```

---

According to the [NuGet documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#packagereference-aliases):

> In some rare instances different packages will contain classes in the same namespace. **Starting with NuGet 5.7 & Visual Studio 2019 Update 7, equivalent to ProjectReference, PackageReference supports Aliases.** By default no aliases are provided. When an alias is specified, all assemblies coming from the annotated package with need to be referenced with an alias.

The documentation also links an [example on GitHub](https://github.com/NuGet/Samples/tree/main/PackageReferenceAliasesExample) showing how to use the `Aliases` attribute:

`PackageReferenceAliasesExample.csproj`:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
  
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="NuGet.Versioning" Version="5.8.0" Aliases="ExampleAlias" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

`Program.cs`:

```cs
extern alias ExampleAlias;
using System;

namespace PackageReferenceAliasesExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var version = ExampleAlias.NuGet.Versioning.NuGetVersion.Parse("5.0.0");
            Console.WriteLine($"Version : {version}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I kept the example generic, so use `BouncyCastle` as the PackageAffectedByConflict, and choose any name (including `BouncyCastle`) for AltGlobalNamespace.